# Toggle Cursorline on/off with one key press

Tags: vim

At the moment I use:

```
map <C-F2> :set cursorcolumn<Bar>set cursorline<CR>
map <C-F3> :set nocursorcolumn<Bar>set nocursorline<CR>
```

How to modify the mapping to toggle on/off only by using C-F2?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
map <C-F2> :set cursorcolumn!<Bar>set cursorline!<CR>
```

From `:help toggle`

```
:se[t] {option}!   or
:se[t] inv{option}  Toggle option: Invert value. {not in Vi}
```